# How do I retrieve the values from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Do you know a good method or tips on how do I retrieve the values (as string) from this multi dimensional array:

```
  array (size=5)
  0 => 
   array (size=1)
      'email' => 
       array (size=1)
       0 => string 'lavidabonita@gmail.com' (length=27)
   1 => 
   array (size=1)
  'email' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'iancasillasbuffon@gmail.com' (length=27)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
     'email' => 
      array (size=1)
      0 => string 'eddynvg@hotmail.com' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
   'email' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'dolphin23@dolphin.net' (length=21)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
   'email' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'dolphin@dolphin.org' (length=19)
```

Comment: Traditionally, we'd write some code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
function fn($arg){
foreach ($arg as $key => $val){
    if (is_array($val)){
        fn($val);
    }
    else{
        echo "$key : $val\n";
    }
}
}

fn($data);
```

Comment: Effective and simple!!